# how to return a promise/future/result form a kotlin suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

If I have a kotlin suspend function like so

```
suspend fun method(request:Request): String
```

Is there any way to do something like so

```
val respFuture: Future = async { method(request) };
respFuture.map { //transform function }
```

I am just curious if there a way here to do something like that.  This is just for understanding of things that 'could' be done and I may never use this pattern.

nothing as of yet as I am more curious

Comment: Yes, and it's exactly what you've shown. `async` returns a `Deferred` which will allow you to call `await` and get a value when it's done.

Comment: Ah, you asked a different question in the body vs the title. No, as far as I know a `Deferred` does not have a `map` method. But you could simply do that mapping inside the first `async` block.

Comment: yeah, I was curious if I could map it to old school future/promises in some other code.

Comment: Yes, I think conversion methods to other async libraries exist, at least for some libraries. I'm not sure which ones exactly, but you should be able to Google for those. [Example](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.future/as-completable-future.html)

Comment: The correct way to map a `Deferred` is simply `async { f(deferred.await()) }`

Answer (score 4):

The various `kotlinx-coroutines` libraries for `reactor`, `reactive`, `guava`, `rx2`, and `rx3` have extension functions for Deferred so you can convert them to these types. For example:

```
val respFuture: Future = coroutineScope.async { method(request) }
    .asCompletableFuture() // Java Future
    // or .asListenableFuture() Guava Future
    // or .asPublisher() Reactive Publisher
    // or .asMono() Reactor Mono
    // or .asSingle() Rx Single
    .map { /* ... */ }
```

There's no separate library for `js`. The `asPromise()` function is included in `kotlinx-coroutines-core`.

and they also have functions for directly creating these types and skipping the step where you create the Deferred:

```
val respFuture: Future = coroutineScope.future { method(request) }
    .map { /* ... */ }
```

`Deferred` itself doesn't have a `map` operator. The way coroutines are designed, you have to provide the CoroutineScope up front, instead of after mapping, so I don't think there's a clean design for mapping to another Deferred that can be passed around and awaited without introducing a new alternative type to Deferred.

---

Edit: just a thought. Maybe a map operator's return type would make sense as an invokable suspend function reference:

```
fun <T, R> Deferred<T>.map(transform: suspend (T)->R): suspend () -> R = suspend {
    transform(await())
}
```